# Running Node.js from the Front End Web Interface on Plesk Onyx panel

Tags: plesk, configuration, node-js

How should we need to run Node.js app especially, from the Web Interface causes Error:403 & 500 Server Error

- Document Root Application will not work because document root is not
  a subchild of application root

[image]

After setting the Document Root to point to the Application Root    structure error disappeared

[image]

- Without even enabling the Node.js startup button

[image]

- After Enabling the Node.js startup button

[image]

**Got 500 Internal Server Error**

When logging from the SSH and running from the terminal it did worked without causing any server error

```
root@user:/var/www/vhosts/somedomain/httpdocs/app# node app.js
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Connected!
^C
root@user:/
```

*and the same code was up and running from Heroku server after allowing remote connections from any host to access our server's database*

- Node.js Version: 9.10.1
- Plesk Onyx 17.8.11

**How should we need to configure the Plesk Onyx panel. So that Forbidden(403) Error & Internal Server Error(500) should be vanished?**

Comment: 403 is generally caused by permissions so ensure you have chmod 0644 on the folder that has the JS.

Comment: For the directory, permission is set with 755 (rwx r-x r-x)
& for *.js file it is set with 644 (rw- r-- r--) @SimonHayter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **403 Forbidden**: The node.js application shows the following error if PHP support is
  set as **PHP FPM handler served by nginx in Domains > example.com > PHP
  Settings:**
- The following error may be found in `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/proxy_error_log` and in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

### Reason:

**Plesk does not support the scenario when PHP-FPM is being used along with Node.js on the same domain.**

### Solutions:

1. If it is necessary to have both PHP and
   Node.js, it is recommended to use separate subdomains for each application.  For 
   example, a site with PHP application —
   www.example.com, chat as Node.js application — chat.example.com. and PHP-FPM is 
   faster when compared to the FastCGI especially in this context with Plesk Onyx panel.
2. Otherwise, change handler type from FPM to the
   FastCGI under **Domains > example.com > PHP Settings**.